# Why does this Firebase Cloud Function function produce the error 'Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted.'

Tags: typescript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that is triggered once a day when the stock market opens. Seems to produce an error 20% of the time it is run.

Error says: 'Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted.'

```
export async function cleanIntraweek() {
  console.log(`cleanIntraweek() started`)

  const min_date_key = moment().tz("America/New_York").subtract(7, 'day').format()

  console.log(`min_date_key: ${min_date_key}`)

  //helper async function to grab some data
  const enabled_stock_keys = await FirebaseObjectFetchService.getStockKeys(true)

  const fetch_intraweek_dataset_promises: Promise<any>[] = []
  const clear_data_promises: Promise<any>[] = []

  for (const stock_key of enabled_stock_keys) {
    const fetch_intraweek_dataset_promise =
      db
        .ref(`charts/${stock_key}/intraweek_v3`)
        .orderByKey()
        .endAt(min_date_key)
        .once("value")
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((child_snapshot) => {
            const clear_data_promise = child_snapshot.ref.remove()
            clear_data_promises.push(clear_data_promise)
            return false
          });
        })
    fetch_intraweek_dataset_promises.push(fetch_intraweek_dataset_promise)
  }

  console.log("waiting on fetch_intraweek_dataset_promises")
  await Promise.all(fetch_intraweek_dataset_promises)

  console.log("waiting on clear_data_promises")
  await Promise.all(clear_data_promises).then(() => {console.log("cleanIntraweek() finished")})

  return null
}
```

I do not remember getting this error when my cloud functions were running on the Node 6 engine. Reverting from the Node 8 engine (current) to Node 6 engine is not a solution because Firebase Cloud Functions is removing Node 6 engine support within a year.

The logs from the most recent erroneous run were:
[image: firebase logs]

I've seen [this post](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/78) but from what I can tell, I do not have any promises that are not awaited before the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

This error typically means that you had some async code running that threw an execption after the function was supposed to be fully complete.  This implies that you're not actually properly handling all the promises in your function.  The problem looks like it's happening here:

```
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((child_snapshot) => {
        const clear_data_promise = child_snapshot.ref.remove()
        clear_data_promises.push(clear_data_promise)
        return false
      });
    })
```

You have a promise callback that is asynchronously creating more promises to delete child nodes.  However, there is nothing here that guarantees `clear_data_promises` will be fully populated **before** that list of promises is being awaited later on.  To put it another way, `await Promise.all(clear_data_promises)` could be executed before `clear_data_promises` is guaranteed to be fully populated, since the forEach lambda is itself not blocking on the results of each operation.

What you will want to do instead is make sure the `then` callback above returns a promise that tracks all the inner promises inside the forEach labmda.  This will make the `fetch_intraweek_dataset_promise` promise resolve only after all the subordinate work is complete.  Something similar to this:

```
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const clear_data_promises = []
      snapshot.forEach((child_snapshot) => {
        const clear_data_promise = child_snapshot.ref.remove()
        clear_data_promises.push(clear_data_promise)
        return false
      });
      return Promise.all(clear_data_promises)
    })
```

Then you will not have to await that array later on.  It will all be resolved with `fetch_intraweek_dataset_promises`.